# How to import new libraries to devstack local.conf without the need to make ./unstack.sh && ./stack.sh?

Tags: server, openstack, openstack-nova, devstack, ceilometer

I want to know if there's a way to update *devstack* libraries when changing `local.conf` without the need of doing: `./unstack.sh && stack.sh`

And if not, then how can I save my temp data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to do this without unstacking it first. I just a post regarding the same [[link]](https://developer.rackspace.com/blog/life-without-devstack-openstack-development-with-osa/). This blog also talks about saving the temp data. Please refer, meanwhile, if I get the exact solution, I'll share the same.